# How do I keep multiple sites in sync using drupal-composer/drupal-project

Tags: drush, composer

What is the correct process to keep local and production sites in sync when using [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). Most of the solutions online only discuss updating one site and not dev, staging and production properties.

This is the current process I am using

1. put live site in maintenance mode
2. run **composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies -vvv**

   - I run this on both local and production servers
   - I noticed that this does not sync alpha and beta contributed modules
   - I noticed that running **'composer update'** from the root of the project updates core and all contrib modules
3. run **drush updb**

   - I run this on both local and production servers
4. I then commit changes to git from the local site

I just want to find out what otheres are doing to keep multiple sites in sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different options that are all viable here; this is what I would suggest:

1. On your dev site, run `composer update` with options to suit what you want to update.
2. Run `drush updb` on your dev site.
3. Test thoroughly; then commit composer.json and composer.lock and push to your repository.
4. On your test site, pull your repository and run `composer install`.  This will put all of your dependencies into the exact same state they were in on your dev site, so you will get exactly what you tested.
5. Run `drush updb` on your test site.
6. Test thoroughly again.
7. When you are ready to deploy to your live site, put it in maitenance mode and use a file copy program (e.g. rsync) to move the exact files from the test site to live. Alternately, you can use `composer install` again.
8. Run `drush updb` on your live site.
9. Confirm that all is okay and take your site out of maintenance mode.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I applied your suggestions. Worked great!